# store config values in javascript

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

I have my store config value as below

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('passwordmeter/validation/is_contain_special_character');
```

How can I Call this value in javascript variable or loop??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want but:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var e = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('passwordmeter/validation/is_contain_special_character'); ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi i have storeconfig value is define in helper->config.php like this

Comment: like this const VALIDATION_IS_CONTAIN_SPECIAL_CHARACTER = 'passwordmeter/validation/is_contain_special_character'; and also function like this public function isContainSpecialCharacter($store = null)
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::VALIDATION_IS_CONTAIN_SPECIAL_CHARACTER, $store);
    }   i need to call this value in root js folder of magento i tried above of your but its not working

Comment: Try again, I had an error in my code

Comment: Hi , can my code located in Unit->PasswordMeter-->Helper->Config.php  i have to pass this value in magento root->js->validation.js and the responsible code is    Validation.add( 'validate-password-is-contain-special-character-passwordmeter',  passwordStrengthMeter.validationConfig.isContainSpecialCharacter.message,function (v) { var password = v.strip();   console.log(r) if(passwordStrengthMeter.validationConfig.isContainSpecialCharacter.isEnabled) {  if (!password.match(/.[!@#$%^&*?_~]/)) { return false;   } } return true; } );

Comment: instead of  if (!password.match(/.[!@#$%^&*?_~]/)) i have to pass Mage::getStoreConfig('passwordmeter/validation/is_contain_special_character'); to check the special character which i put in admin->is contain special character tab = $#!